# Redirect or send mail in a script that runs in a rule on incoming mails in outlook 2010

Tags: script, microsoft-outlook-2010, redirection, send-to

I have the following problem:

- I have a mails that are arriving in my mailbox
- these mails contain a specific string in the body
- what I want to do is:

  - --> removing this string from the body
  - --> then send this body to another mail address (send, not forward)

**What have I already done:**

**A.** Created a rule that activates the script in incoming messages that contain a certain string in the description

This is the rule description:

```
Apply to message
with "Maileater" in the subject
  and on this computer only
run "Project1.ChangeString"
```

**B.** Created the script with the following instructions:

Public Sub ChangeString(MyMail As MailItem)

```
   Dim body As String
   body = MyMail.body

   body = Replace (body, "=====================================================", " ")
   MyMail.body = body

   MyMail.Save
End Sub
```

**C.** Now I want to add in the script the instruction to send the body (or MyMail.body) to a specific mail address (e.g. Support@AXA.be with description "Support asked") after the replacement of the string.

Is this possible?

Can someone help me with this, I would be very greatfull because this will eliminate a lot of manual work for me.

This is just an exemple of a mail, the real thing will contain other replacements and mails to send.